# How to prevent database field injection?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a *model*, described in the following manner:

```
@Table
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    // ...skipped...
    private String foo;
}
```

I also have a *service* with a method that creates a new entity:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    // ...skipped...
    public User createUser(User user) {
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        user.setCreated(currentDate);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

I also have a *controller* and a mapped method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(UserRouteRegistry.FIRST_LEVEL + "/*")
public class UserController {
    // ...skipped...
    @PostMapping(UserRouteRegistry.SIGN_UP)
    public String signUp(
            @ModelAttribute("user") @Validated(User.CreateUserGroup.class) User user,
            BindingResult result,
            WebRequest request,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes
    ) {
    // ...mercellessly skipped...
                userRegistered = userService.createUser(user);
    // ...mercellessly skipped...
    }
```

Everything is pretty straightforward, right?

I do NOT have the `foo` field in the web-form and I do NOT need a web-user to set this field, it should be some really private field that should NOT be affected by a web-user directly.

When I make a custom POST request, I see that a new entity is being created with the `foo` field filled by the data that was set in the request:

```
POST /user/sign-up HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Origin:  http://127.0.0.1:8080
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer:  http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/sign-up
Cookie:  SL_G_WPT_TO=ru; SL_GWPT_Show_Hide_tmp=1; SL_wptGlobTipTmp=1; BL_D_PROV=; BL_T_PROV=; JSESSIONID=E1190293BD183C647245BAE03E6DCDDA
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e572bccf-ff0a-4b0b-a181-dd0aa20dca99
foo=13
```

```
> SELECT foo FROM user ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
foo: 13
1 row in set (0.0005 sec)
```

Yes, it seems pretty correct, but what is there a way to **prevent** that somehow?

Assigning the "private" fields the `null` value on the *service* level? That would be pretty tedious, but it would work. Setting some @annotation (by the way, what annotation should it be?) to this field on the *model* level? I'm not sure it would be logical, as for my opinion. Filtering the parameters on the *controller* level, listing all the allowed ones somewhere? Maybe so?

What is the correct way?

Thank you!

Comment: Data includes ToString and HashAndEquals annotations.

Comment: Thank you, @Antoniossss, I'll keep that in mind and consider to remove the unnecessary annotations.

Comment: *I do NOT have the zaloopa field in the web-form and I do NOT need a web-user to set this field* and * I see that a new entity is being created with the zaloopa field filled by the data that was set in the request* so why it is in your request in first place if you "dont have" that on form?

Comment: @Antoniossss, it was a manual request made by Postman. I performed it to see what will happen if a user tries to do the same sidestepping the form. To check, if my app is vulnerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practice to separate the model and DTO - DTO that you transfer between frontend & backend controller- because sometimes there can be a lot more that just one field to exclude or handle differently. Also it can be that that field is needed in some other context so it can not be excluded in model itself.

So while your controller now receives `User` model it should receive `UserDTO` that has only the needed allowed fields.

This of course makes things bit more difficult because you then need to map `UserDTO` between `User`. But luckily there are libraries to handle that also like [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one question regarding this concept, if you don't mind. If I have `User` and `UserDTO` objects and my controller works with `UserDTO`, where should I place my validation annotations such as `@NotNull`, `@NotEmpty` and my custom validations to check the email validity, password strength and other things? Right now I have them in the `User` object and controller defines what validation group should be used:
`public String signUp(@ModelAttribute("user") @Validated(User.CreateUserGroup.class) User user ...`

Comment: Ah, I understood!

Some validations should be performed on the model level, some validations should be pefrormed on the DTO level (and it's OK if some of them are duplicated there and there), right? :)

Comment: @AlanHay I agree to some extent but I justify the good practice also because it allows decoupling layers. If it was some nosql service on the persistence side, for example, you would not need to change the controller and maybe not even manager stuff.

Comment: @VladimirMelnik even it feels boilerplate we have made bean validation on the DTO side & the JPA related validations - naturally -on the entity side.

Comment: Thank you, @pirho, I've implemented DTOs and it feels really good for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore that field on deserialization

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
private String zaloopa;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are posting **form data** then you can do so as below i.e. by creating a method annotated with the `@InitBinder` method and then setting a list of disallowed fields on the supplied `WebDataBinder` instance.

This method can be added to your controller, a Spring MVC Controller Advice or both. For fields shared by all entities you can add on a Controller advice and then register additional entity specific fields on the relevant controller.

```
@InitBinder()
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields(new String[] { "id", "version" });
}
```

If you were posting **JSON data** then you could do so by means of Jackson annotations. You can place these directly an an entity's fields or you can use Jackson mixin classes to avoid having to "pollute" the domain model with web tier concerns.

Annotate the field in either the entity or in the mixin:

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
private String myField;
```

To register a mixin:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer addMixin(){
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.mixIn(User.class, UserMixin.class);                
        }
    };
}
```