# How to dynamically avoid sending response containing all properties from relationship data

Tags: json, spring-boot, jax-rs, spring-rest

I am new to spring boot and rest and hence pardon me if this question is very trivial.

I have a situation where the application allows users to register and place order.
On registration of user, the service should be able to send a response with the user information including - User Name, email, contact Number, address etc.

However, while placing orders, I would like the order response object to include within the order details, only the customer (username, email). I do not want to include the address and other information part of the User object.

Currently, what is happening is whenever, I refer to an existing user instance within the Order instance, the Order response has the complete tuple information of the registered user.

In the Order confirmation response, I really do not want the entire User information.

However, if the same Order entity is being referenced for user register, I want the service to include all fields from the Order entity.

I have tried referring to the following links -

[Jackson Change JsonIgnore Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179986/jackson-change-jsonignore-dynamically)
[How do I exclude fields with Jackson not using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764280/how-do-i-exclude-fields-with-jackson-not-using-annotations)

However, the solutions mentioned here will always ignore the attribute in response irrespective of the scenario in which the entity is being referenced.

For example - Response from Order service is as below.

```
{
    "id": "ORD-1000",
    "priority": null,
    "status": "Open",
    "customer": {
        "id": "1000",
        "name": "Avion Solutions",
        "email": "support-na@avionsolutions.com",
        "contact": null,
        "customerType": "gold-sx",
        "shipToContactId": null,
        "billToContactId": null
    },
    "urgency": null
}
```

In the above response tuple, lets say, I just want the order information with basic customer information such as name & email.

And if the customer is registering, then the response should contain all the information as mentioned in the above tuple.

How can i dynamically ignore the attributes in response of the REST service based on the context in which the entity object is being used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to use separate DTOs not the for different data transfer cases. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54764493/6413377) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@JsonView` annotation. You can define visibility for given property and on `REST` `Controller` you can define level you want to show. For more information and examples, please, read below:

1. [Jackson JSON Views](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation)
2. [Jackson – Bidirectional Relationships](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)
3. [Using @JsonView with Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772304/using-jsonview-with-spring-mvc)